# SIP client to open a web page with caller ID

Tags: voip, sip, caller-id

Does anyone know of a SIP client that can open a web page to a configurable URL when someone calls? We have a web-based database, and I'd like to search by phone number whenever we get an incoming call, and have the person on screen before I answer it.

The SIP client program doesn't have to have any other audio or calling features - we all have hardware SIP phones on our desks as well.

Comment: Maybe create a desktop shortcut/hotkey for the database instead? Personally, I prefer something that's predictable over something the computer can screw up on.

Comment: rjmunro, did you ever get an answer to this problem? I am looking for something identical - a softphone client that loads a URL to go along with hardware phones.

Comment: @ChristopherPadfield I never did get a solution to this problem. I'm now working somewhere else, where it would be less useful, but am still interested.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that you're still looking for an answer to this 6 months later, but here goes:

The [Twinkle SIP client](http://www.xs4all.nl/~mfnboer/twinkle) supports executing a script when an incoming call is received and I'm sure many others do as well.  To get something like this working in Twinkle, you'd write a script like the one below, then go into Edit->User Profile->Scripts and select /path/to/my/script for "Incoming Call".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re

def get_caller_id(from_hdr):
    clid, uri = from_hdr.split(" <sip")
    clid = re.sub("\"", "", clid)
    # Insert ASCII code for spaces
    if re.search("\s", clid):
        clid = re.sub("\s", "%20", clid)
    return clid


if "SIP_FROM" in os.environ:
    from_hdr = os.environ["SIP_FROM"]
    if re.match("\"[A-Za-z0-9\s]+\"", from_hdr):
        cmd = "firefox "
        url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
        caller_id = get_caller_id(from_hdr)
        cmd_string = cmd + url + caller_id

        # Launch Browser
        os.system(cmd_string)
```

Comment: I am still looking for an answer, and that looks nice, but none of our clients use Linux, which Twinkle seems to require

Comment: I modified your script a little so it opens a browser and starts a search on a website (www.numeroinconnu.fr) that informs me about the caller. A great way to avoid "harcèlement téléphonique"!

Answer (score 2):

I found http://www.phoner.de/index_en.htm does this. Options -> External Application and then run a .bat file with something like:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com/id=%1
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've added options to automatically open URL on incoming call or on accepting incoming call to [tSIP](http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/) (Settings/Contacts, HTTP query, e.g. https://www.yandex.com/search/?text=[number] where "[number]" would be replaced with number from current or last incoming call). Previously it was available only as manual action and personally I would prefer it that way. All function keys are configurable (BLF/speed dial/DTMF/etc., similar to desk phones). After configuring "HTTP query" button, global shortcut (e.g. Ctrl + Browser Forward key combination that most likely would be unused) can be assigned to it making it relatively effortless to open page if softphone sits it tray (action for shortcut = "button #", ID = button ID as visible when editing button).

I don't know how call queue works with your PABX (sequential or all-at-once ringing), but opening pages automatically may result with lots of pages opened unnecessary (or be very disturbing if agents are making notes after the call) and I think in many cases agents may know that particular call should be left to be answered by their peers.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use WebRTC from web.

This can be easily done with the siplml5 or [JsSIP](http://jssip.net/) open source WebRTC clients.

Or if you wish a ready to use solution you might try the mizu [webphone](http://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/WebPhone.aspx) which has a setting for this, so you just have to enter your URL to be called on incoming calls.

Comment: I don't think you have understood what I needed. I wanted something that can sit in the task bar, logged into my SIP account. When a call comes in, I want it to open a URL in a new window with the caller ID added, e.g. http://example.com/search?phone=1234567890, which my database will use to look up the person who is calling.